# How to run Google Chrome with Selenium RC?

Tags: asp.net, nunit, selenium

I am trying to test my site with Selenium RC + Nunit + asp.net.

I can get my tests to work in Firefox,Safari,opera,IE 8 but not google chrome. I put this in for the browser arugment

```
 selenium = new DefaultSelenium(Server, ServerPort,
                                          "*chrome", DomainURL);
```

This always loads up Firefox though and not good chrome.

Comment: The page your script is trying to open doesn't exist.So you are getting 404 error.You'll get same error when you run the test case in any of the browsers.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If I remember correctly, **"`*chrome`" is used to launch a special mode of Firefox** *(a mode in which your application has more privilegies -- with less security restrictions)* ; so, the fact that it's Firefox that is launched, and not Google Chrome, is normal.

If you want to launch Google Chrome, you will have to use something else than "`*chrome`".

Using Selenium RC in interactive mode, with something like this :

```
$ java -jar selenium-server.jar -interactive
```

and using the `getNewBrowserSession` command not correctly :

```
cmd=getNewBrowserSession
```

I get the list of browsers is supports :

```
23:43:09.317 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Browser not supported:
(Did you forget to add a *?)

Supported browsers include:
  *firefox
  *mock
  *firefoxproxy
  *pifirefox
  *chrome
  *iexploreproxy
  *iexplore
  *firefox3
  *safariproxy
  *googlechrome
  *konqueror
  *firefox2
  *safari
  *piiexplore
  *firefoxchrome
  *opera
  *iehta
  *custom
 on session null
```

So, I'm guessing **you should be able to launch Google Chrome using "`*googlechrome`"** instead of "`*chrome`".

I'm not on Windows, so I can't try by myself... And I cannot find anything in the documentation to back me up... Still, with a bit of luck, this might help you...

Anyway, have fun !

*As a sidenote : Google Chrome is not the one which invented the term "chrome", actually ; it means [plenty of things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome), like [Chrome Mozilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Mozilla) or [User Interface Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_chrome)*

Comment: Ya that worked. I just thought they shortened it to chrome or something like that. Thanks

Comment: I never used Google Chrome with Selenium RC, but I remembered having seen "*chrome" well before Google Chrome actually existed ; so, it seemed strange to use that to launch it ^^. You're welcome :-) Have fun!

Comment: Thanks very much, looked for solution for this for long time.

Answer (score 6):

Using the browser `*googlechrome` is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Actually "`*chrome`" represented by Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *googlechrome else use ***custom path_to_Chrome.exe** file

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the chrome.exe path in to the path variable, give directly *googlechrome in place of *chrome else give the path of chrome.exe along with that.

Eg/

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*googlechrome C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe","http://www.google.com");
```