# How to explicitly specify a path to Firefox for Selenium?

Tags: python, windows, firefox, testing, selenium

I got Selenium IDE, followed [this post](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html), got to

```
python test_default_server.py
```

and it complains Firefox is not in my path:

```
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3c:\blah\firefox.exe
```

I could change my PATH environment variable, but I'd rather pursue the local config option they are mentioning ("explicitly specify a path"). How do I do that? What does the "*firefox3c" refer to?

Selenium 1.0.1, Python 2.5, Windows XP.

Comment: I assume there is a missing character in there, and it should be something like: firefox3=c:\blah\firefox.exe

Comment: The missing character is a space.

Answer (score 16):

You have to use the following string when you instantiate selenium instead of just "*firefox":

```
"*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
```

Notice: I'm not sure that path is correct, but it should be a similar one.

Update: Where do you instantiate your browser?
By the tags in the question I suppose you're a python guy:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://change-this-to-the-site-you-are-testing/")
    self.selenium.start()
```

Comment: where do you instantiate selenium?  You mean at the command line?  Is it a command-line arg?

Comment: Notice that you'll neet to add r as a prefix to "*firefox..." as it - r"*firefox C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe". This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: One reason this doesn't work is that Python uses \ to escape characters.  You need to make it /, or \\.

Comment: The path "*firefox C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" should be updated with correct answer to avoid unnecessary bug finding, either r"*firefox C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" or "*firefox C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"

Comment: Apparently this issue has resurfaced for Windows 7 64-bit in the most recent 2.0 beta: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-737

Comment: I apologize I have not tested the solution because I do not have the environment to test it anymore, I'd have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

If on C# editor, use the following string:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files\\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Note: use an extra back slash before Program Files and firefox.exe, since a single backslash becomes an unrecognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://change-this-to-the-site-you-are-testing/")
```

Worked in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This helps very much. `setUp("http://localhost:8080/BingDemo/BingDriver.html", "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe");`

However, replace all occurrences of `\` with `\\` in *firefox `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`

Additionally, you could point your PATH to in environmental variables to `mozilla.exe`

Answer (score 1):

For Java Solution using Selenium Webdriver, you can import the below class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
```

and use the code snippet below to instantiate a new driver by explicitly specifying the path to the firefox.exe in your local system.

```
DesiredCapabilities browserCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxBinary ffbinary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"));
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffbinary, ffprofile, browserCapabilities);
```

Note: You may need to replace "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe*" with the path that points to firefox.exe on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The *firefox etc are the keys for which browser to use to run the tests.

There is a long list of them at [How to run Google Chrome with Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317055/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-selenium-rc/1317131#1317131) - so you can target Firefox v2 (*firefox2), Firefox v3 (*firefox3), Google Chrome (*googlechrome) etc

Comment: in the initialisation,
i.e. selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://stackoverflow.com");

Replace the "*chrome" bit with any of those keys to target a different browser

Answer (score 0):

This helps very much.

```
setUp("http://localhost:8080/BingDemo/BingDriver.html", "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it worth useful...

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://gmail.com");
```