# Firefox not closing after selenium tests are run

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium

Firefox runs, but when the tests finish executing Firefox stays up.

This is on Debian Linux with Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was to point Selenium at the firefox-bin file instead of the firefox file, which it may use by default if it's at /usr/bin/firefox.

This question explains how to specify a path to firefox-bin:
[How to explicitly specify a path to Firefox for Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344026/how-to-explicitly-specify-a-path-to-firefox-for-selenium)

Comment: You should "Accept" you own question so that others can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks. It used to be that somebody has to up-vote your question before you can accept it. Either that changed or I have enough reputation to do it without the up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me when using the [screenshot taking functionality](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase.examples.WebTest2.php) and selecting a non-existing folder to store the screenshots. As seen on [this other scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847048/phpunit-selenium-capturescreenshotonfailure-does-not-work), PHPUnit's error handling is rather bad.