# rspec+capybara+selenium+spork not closing browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec2, capybara, spork

The same problem with rails tests as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436076/firefox-not-closing-after-selenium-tests-are-run), but on Mac OS X.

And when I start specs next time, they hang on js specs until I close the browser manually. And those tests fail, I need to restart specs again.

What's the solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/timcharper/spork/issues/144

1) [optional] to close only my processes

`cp /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin-selenium`

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin-selenium"
```

2)

```
Spork.each_run do
\`killall firefox-bin-selenium\`
end
```