# How could I control the Chrome web browser with Java black-box unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-chrome

Is there a library to control Chrome browser in black-box unit testing? I prefer Java, coming from a WATIJ/WATIN testing background.  I am wondering what options are out there and/or if there is anything on the burner for something like this?

Comment: Do you want to test the javascript in Chrome, or are you going to test the browser itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Selenium RC for this kind of testing. It supports Chrome and a lot of other browsers. This post has more details: [How to run Google Chrome with Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317055/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-selenium-rc)

Comment: Thanks. I am still considering sticking to WATIJ+Maven2+JUnit4 and just not worrying about Chrome. I'll research Selenium but I'd rather not rely on a recorder IDE... I'd rather code from scratch using Java. Selenium may work well without the IDE but Im not seeing much information about people doing it that way.

Comment: Selenium RC is designed specifically for programmatic control. You can write your test scripts specifying selectors (using either xpath, css or plain javascript) and assert expected values.