# Selenium Capabilities

Tags: junit, selenium, cruisecontrol, junit4

I'm drowning in the Selenium documentation.  What I've got so far is the ability to record a script in FireFox, export it to the new WebDriver format (JUnit4), open and tweak the test in Eclipse, then run it as a JUnit test in Eclipse.

What I'm wanting next:

- to run the same test on multiple browsers
- to have a suite of tests run on a remote server at a set interval
- receive notification if a test fails

Is this possible using the path I've started down above?  It's hard to tell, but I'm not sure that WebDriver is compatible with the RC server.  Or, should I just take my suite of JUnit tests and integrate them with something like Cruise Control?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

> to run the same test on multiple browsers

See: [How to run Google Chrome with Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317055/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-selenium-rc)

> to have a suite of tests run on a remote server at a set interval

This is hard, especially when you are running on headless (terminal only) machine. See [this article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/developer/2008/05/confluence_has_a_selenium_buil.html). But not impossible, read further.

> receive notification if a test fails

The typical configuration is to use CI server like Bamboo, take advantage of [`cargo-maven-plugin`](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) to deploy your application and run Selenium tests during `integration-test` phase. Easier said than done. Since CI server is typically headless, you will need freaks of nature like [`xvfb`](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Selenium-RC+and+Continuous+Integration), taking a lot of screenshots since you have no idea what is happening during the build when it fails, and so on... But it is possible, we managed to setup such a process in our company and are very happy for it.

Comment: I tried using the ChromeWebDriver, but no love there.  For now, I think I'll just settle for having the tests run successfully in Firefox and not use Selenium to validate browser compatibility.  As far as CI goes, I think we're moving towards using Hudson, so I will check out my options there.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Bromine helps you to run on several browsers. Regarding "Scheduling" as already said, maven would help. Try to gather infos about Hudson. It helps a lot in scheduling. It supports selenium too. It helps to send notification also.

Comment: Our architects are pushing the use of Hudson, so I'll definitely check it out, thanks!