# Is there javascript framework to run the unit tests based on the browser type

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I explored the javascript unit test libraries ( qunit, jasmine ), but my requirement is run the unit test scripts based on the browser type on runtime.

that means, if i run the unit test scripts first i need to identify running browser type ( ex: chrome ) using the framework and run only related browser test cases.

Comment: I believe Selenium can handle this

Answer (score 2):

[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920353/how-to-change-web-browser-from-firefox-to-chrome-opera-ie-safari-in-selenium-web)

There isn't a whole lot of information for me to go off of, but it seems that this post is similar.

To answer your question, Selenium can probably handle what you're looking for, but it will depend on your exact needs not specified in this post.

Answer (score 0):

This one: 
https://saucelabs.com/javascript/

Seems to have an option for configuring the browser before run the test.

Hope is enough, haven't really tried it myself.