# How to launch chrome browser using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

When am trying to launch chrome browser using selenium it throws me error.

Am using this command in my code "selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.google.com/");

Comment: Look at this question [here it is]


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317055/how-to-run-google-chrome-with-selenium-rc

It reamains the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you want to launch Google Chrome, you will have to use something else than "*chrome".

Using Selenium RC in interactive mode, with something like this

$ java -jar selenium-server.jar -interactive
and using the getNewBrowserSession command not correctly :

cmd=getNewBrowserSession
I get the list of browsers is supports :

23:43:09.317 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Browser not supported:
(Did you forget to add a *?)

Supported browsers include:
  *firefox
  *mock
  *firefoxproxy
  *pifirefox
  *chrome
  *iexploreproxy
  *iexplore
  *firefox3
  *safariproxy
  *googlechrome
  *konqueror
  *firefox2
  *safari
  *piiexplore
  *firefoxchrome
  *opera
  *iehta
  *custom
 on session null
So, I'm guessing you should be able to launch Google Chrome using "*googlechrome" instead of "*chrome".

-reference -  sir pascal martin . :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Selenium RC?

I use WebDriver, and the code that I used to open Chrome is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<localpath of Chrome driver>");
WebDriver chromeobj = new ChormeDriver();
chromeobj.get("www.google.com");
```